# Custom Calendar list shows only Custom Columns while creating new event

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-calendar

I have created one custom calendar list in SharePoint hosted app and when I am trying to create new event it is not showing defaults columns(start date ,end date...etc) along with my custom created columns.

[image]

Can any one tell me why it is happening?

I am using content type and in which I have some custom columns and these only getting displayed along with title while creating new event.

Comment: Your custom content type should inherit from `Event` content type.

Comment: how to make it inheritable from event content type?in my elemts.xml file there is property Inherits="TRUE" ,with this i have to do something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely your custom content type is deriving from `Item` content type. You need to inherit it from `Event` content type. If you are adding a content type using Visual Studio, you are presented with an option to select the parent content type as shown:
[image: Choose Content Type]

However, if you already have created it, you can still modify the Elements.xml file. Id of `Event` is `0x0102`. Append this value in ID property of Content Type followed by the GUID. Example:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <!-- Parent ContentType: Event (0x0102) -->
  <ContentType ID="0x010200B5BDA8DA0B8944F0AE8ACE1A38228A59"
               Name="Holiday"
               Group="Custom Content Types"
               Description="My Content Type"
               Inherits="TRUE"
               Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
    </FieldRefs>
  </ContentType>
</Elements>
```